# salesforce aura:attribute how to create array of user defined class

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I want to display list of Animals that I am fetching from external system.How can I define aura:attribute for my class Animal.
 
I do not want to store it in salesforce.I would like to know where can i define Animal class and create an array for it so that I can display a list of animals in my component

Comment: Ideally, it would be good if you added the code you were attempting here in your question, then in your answer, showing how you fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My mistake!I have created an Inner Class in my Component's Controller Class thinking that my current component will have access to only the controller class.I created a normal class and marked attributes with @AuraEnabled and it worked.Thanks!

Comment: Then this is a bug .It should have worked with inner classes as well...